# jolt spec to remove 0 byte files

Tags: json, specifications, jolt

I am trying to find only file names having valid size >0 using jolt.

```json
{
  "objectName": "data",
  "path": "/user/testuser/test_project/processing",
  "type": "directory",
  "owner": "testuser",
  "group": "testuser",
  "length": "2733",
  "countFiles": "7",
  "countDirs": "1",
  "content": [
    {
      "objectName": "part-00000-f56d8bfa-2a3d-438c-89a5-d9a2460e6c66-c000.json",
      "path": "/user/testuser/test_project/processing/data",
      "type": "file",
      "owner": "testuser",
      "group": "testuser",
      "length": "0"
    },
    {
      "objectName": "part-00043-f56d8bfa-2a3d-438c-89a5-d9a2460e6c66-c000.json",
      "path": "/user/testuser/test_project/processing/data",
      "type": "file",
      "owner": "testuser",
      "group": "testuser",
      "length": "782"
    }
  ]
}
```

Below is my jolt spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "content": {
        "*": {
          "type": {
            "file": {
              "@2": "files[]"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "files": {
        "*": {
          "objectName": {
            "*": {
              "@2": "files[]"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "files": {
        "*": {
          "objectName": "files.[&1].filename",
          "path": "files.[&1].filepath",
          "length": "files.[&1].filesize"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

In the output i want only the files having size greater than 0

currently it gives

```json
{
  "files": [
    {
      "filename": "part-00000-f56d8bfa-2a3d-438c-89a5-d9a2460e6c66-c000.json",
      "filepath": "/user/testuser/test_project/processing/data",
      "filesize": "0"
    },
    {
      "filename": "part-00043-f56d8bfa-2a3d-438c-89a5-d9a2460e6c66-c000.json",
      "filepath": "/user/testuser/test_project/processing/data",
      "filesize": "782"
    }
  ]
}
```

I Tried using remove jolt spech but i can only find examples of removing null values , not sure how to remove numbers or using a filter like length > 0 .

Also tried using shift operator with "0" and "*" on length attribute, but it doesn't remove the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use successive **shift** transformations along with a conditional logic to separate the case when `length = 0` or `!=0`, and lastly use a **remove** transformation to drop the unnecessary attribute such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&", // elements other than "content" array
      "content": {
        "*": {
          "length": {
            "0": "AttributeToRemove", // case when length  = 0
            "*": { // case when length != 0
              "@(2,objectName)": "files.&3.filename",
              "@(2,path)": "files.&3.filepath",
              "@1": "files.&3.filesize"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "fi*": {
        "*": {
          "@": "&2[]" // go 2 levels up the tree to grab the literal `files` to replicate by using &2
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // get rid of redundantly generated attribute due to length  = 0 case
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "AttributeToRemove": ""
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]